# Django check_token(user, token) fails in view but works in test/shell_plus?

Tags: python, django

Getting the strangest behavior. This fails in normal Django code (view):

```py
user = User.objects.get(...)
uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)

print("CHECK TOKEN:", default_token_generator.check_token(to, token))
# this prints True!

send_email_function(user, uid, token)
# When using password reset email, token is denied
```

Then when using the token to reset password, the password reset view claims the token is invalid. If I make a management command that calls the same code to send a password reset email: the token works!

This works in `shell_plus`, same code basically:

```py
>>> from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
>>> from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
>>> from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
>>> user = User.objects.last()
>>> token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
>>> default_token_generator.check_token(user, token)
True
```

I've printed out the `SECRET_KEY` in each case and that seems fine. Inspecting the `make_token` function has lead me to trying to set a `password` and `last_login` which have not helped.

Very confusing!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I've spent 1 day trying to figure it out what is happening and still not resolved yet  =/

Comment: @ViniciusChan I actually don't remember how we fixed it, but I think `last_login` or something was the culprit. I believe we ended up sending the email with the token after a 30 second delay and _that_ worked.

Now it's kinda coming back to me, maybe we were sending the token'd email before logging the user in? The 30 second delay allowed the user to be logged into our site and still receive the secret token + use it successfully

if this is helpful please upvote question!